# Decrypt an encrypted file/folder.

Tags: encryption, password-encryption

I have a encrypted file and i am aware of its password. I am trying to decrypt it but i could not find any properties of this file such as the type of algorithm/program that was used to encrypt the file originally.

I am thinking to try 'gpg' and 'openssl' and other techniques that can be used to decrypt this file without corrupting it. Although i have taken the backup, it's a huge file which takes roughly 3hrs for backing up.  Hence i am extra careful so that it does not goes corrupt.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you asking us to list all of the possible means by which an unknown file could have been encrypted? That's not a programming questi on. This is not a *please speculate about what I might be asking, and make me a list of things that might possibly be an answer* site. What **specifically** can we help you with?

Comment: Where did you get this file?  From a crashed spaceship, the CIA, Edward Snowden, a North Korean double agent, some specific internet site?  More practically, is it from a Linux, Windows, or Apple system?  Is it a self-executing archive (have you tried executing it)?  A passworded zip file (tried unzupping it?). A symmetric GPG file ?

Comment: Also, this question is probably off topic for Stack Overflow as there is not a specific programming question.  It might be on topic on Super User or Information Security, but even they would need some more information in order to help you.

Comment: This is encrypted file from our previous company. We forgot(dont know)  how the engineer encrypted it, but he gave the password to us. Now trying to look in the file.

Comment: The solution, then, is to contact the former employee.  Surely a small consulting fee or other favor for the employee would be the least expensive way to deal with this, rather than spending many hours of your own or others time to guess or work around?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way anyone can help you unless you find out more information about the file. Just knowing the password is not enough. This question is far too open-ended, as the other commenters have mentioned, and you will have to find out how the file was encrypted.

Comment: OK, thanks Paul and Ken suggestions. I am going to ask in the community mentioned by you. We contacted our previous employee, he can't remember what he did 6 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, you are going to have to find out what program was used to encrypt the file, and maybe, possibly (but probably not) have to know how the program was configured.  People have been using computers for encryption almost as long as computers have existed.  There are hundreds of different encryption programs that have been published over the years.

Your best bet is to get the developer to tell you which program he used and how to use it.

Your next best bet is to search through your backups of every machine he used looking for some clue as to what program he used.

If that doesn't help, it's time to start trying every encryption program you can get hold of.  Obviously, you'll want to start with the newer ones, and the more popular ones, and the ones that run on whatever operating systems he was known to use.

Considering the size of the file, it's likely that you're dealing with an encrypted *archive* or, an image of an encrypted *file system*.  So, don't limit your search to specialized encryption utilities. You'll also want to try all of the different archivers and all of the different file systems and operating systems that offer encryption as a feature.

If you've tried every encryption program without success, and you still haven't blown your budget; then the next step is going to blow your budget.  I'm pretty confident in saying that because if your organization was the kind that could afford to take the next step, then you wouldn't be asking how to do it on StackOverflow.  Heck!  You probably would not even be allowed to *use* StackOverflow without written permission from three levels up the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea of encryption is that the result should be indistinguishable from the noise.

That automatically means, that unless you know all the parameters, you won't be able to infer it from the encrypted file if it was done right.

Unless you brute force all the possible types of encryption and their parameters (good luck with that!).

Comment: Can you pls tell what types of 'parameters' are needed for decrypting? We  have the password for it that's all we got.

Comment: @vkb have you actually read my answer?

Comment: Sorry ! and thank you so much for quick reply.  You mentioned 'all parameters' hence i am wondering what does all include.

Comment: @vkb no one can know that :-) It would depend on the actual encryption algorithm used.